# How to make the taskbar floating and compact (move the taskbar to a corner to save space and make transparent)?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, gui, desktop-customization, user-interface

I never have many windows (since they are spread out between multiple desktop) and I never click the taskbar icons (`<Win> + <Number>` is more convenient for me), so I'd like to hide taskbar.

I don't want to activate auto-hide because I still want to see the clock and icons of currently opened windows at all times.

I think the best option would be to make the taskbar not fill the whole horizontal space but make it floating like this:

[image: Taskbar example]

[Source, with more examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7D11.jpg)

P.S. Yes, I am aware that this customization is not a part of the official functionality, so the use of 3rd party tools or deeper tweaking is expected.

Comment: It's possible to make the taskbar transparent by using https://github.com/TranslucentTB/TranslucentTB

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard option of Windows, so it needs a third-party product.

You could get
[ObjectDock](https://www.stardock.com/products/objectdock/)
by Stardock, which can do very many customizations.
It is however a commercial product with a 30-days trial.